# Show that $f$ can not be expanded into a power series in a neighborhood of $0$.

Tags: power-series

Let $f(x)$ be defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},& \text{ if }x \neq 0,\\0, &\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$ 
Show that $f$ can not be expanded into a power series in a neighborhood of $0$.

We know that $f$ must be infinitely differentiable to be able to expand into a power series and $e^{-1/x^2}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!\cdot x^{2n}}$ . Then what can we do next? Anyone help me please?

Comment: A power series cannot include negative exponents.

Comment: Can you tell me why? Isn't right for every $x \in R$?

Comment: It is right for every $x\in\mathbb R$, but if you make a series expansion involving anything like $\frac1{x^n}$, it is called a laurent series, not a power series, and it has different properties, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to compute all the derivatives $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$, etc, they are all zero.

So, if $f$ could be expanded into a power series in a neighborhood of 0, it would be the zero function there.

This is a contradiction, as $f$ is not the zero function in any neighborhood of 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can find an answer here: [A POSITIVE SMOOTH FUNCTION WITH ALL DERIVATIVES VANISHING AT ZERO](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/positive-smooth-function-with-all-derivatives-vanishing-at-zero/).